# If klgk = Θ(n), then k = Θ(n/lgn)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Ok so first off I'm new to this site so if by some chance I'm doing anything wrong please let me know.  I need help with the following proof.  I am NOT looking for the answer, simply guidance.

Using the definition of Θ, prove the following:
If klgk = Θ(n), then k = Θ(n/lgn).

My professor told us to start with k < n.  Then take the log of both sides, giving us lg(k) < lg(n).  Then multiply both sides by k, finally giving us k*lgk < k*lgn.  From here we can say k*lgn <= c2*n, and dividing both sides by lgn, we have k <= c2 * (n/lgn).  Thus k = O(n/lgn).  Why is it that in the beginning we can say that k < n?  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because big-theta (also) gives you an upper bound, so you have `klgk < n` from `klgk = big-theta(n)`, therefore also `k < n`.

Comment: +up vote for welcome to stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
Big Theta:
```

[image] ==> [image] (for some positive k1, k2) &

f is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically    =====>

[image]  : [image]

so for your question ==>  [image] :::: n . k1 <= ( k . log k ) <= n . k2

====> k . ( log k / k2 ) < n

when parameter continues to Extreme then ( log k / k2 ) > 1 ,so k < n